# TinyMCE stripping embed code in Drupal 6 using Wysiwyg module

Tags: drupal, video, embed, stripping

I have a Drupal 6 installation with a Wysiwyg profile set up to use TinyMCE. The profile has the media button turned on. I have defined the Filtered HTML input format to allow the `<embed>`, `<object>`, and `<param>` tags and made this the default format for all roles. When you use the media button (the thing that looks like a couple frames of film) and enter a url, code like the following is generated and visible in the source:

```
<object width="100" height="100" data="http://youtu.be/wEWSHWp5vHM" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="data" value="http://youtu.be/wEWSHWp5vHM" />
    <param name="src" value="http://youtu.be/wEWSHWp5vHM" />
</object>
```

However, when you preview or save the post, the video is not rendered.

Here is the list of allowed tags:

```
<a> <em> <strong> <cite> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd><form><input><br><p><div><span><img><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><table><tr><td><thead><th><tbody><iframe><embed><object><param>
```

Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I found this recent post that seems to imply that you need to set TinyMCE to not use media_strict, but I can't believe you have to add a homebrew module to get embedding to work: http://drupal.org/node/368388#comment-5501684

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try embedding using 'Full HTML Filter'? You might also create a whole new input filter type for this content type.